# Type safe type combinations with shapeless

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

Having the following code:

```
import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil, Lazy}

object Problem {
  trait In {
    def bar: Double
  }

  trait A {
    def foo: Int
    type I <: In
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  final case class A1In(d: Double) extends In {
    override def bar: Double = 1.1 + d
  }

  final case class A1() extends A {
    override def foo: Int = 1
    override type I = A1In
  }

  final case class A2In(d: Double) extends In {
    override def bar: Double = 1.1 + d
  }

  final case class A2() extends A {
    override def foo: Int = 1
    override type I = A2In
  }


  final case class AListIn[T <: HList](items: T)(implicit ev: isIn[T]) extends In {
    override def bar = 1.1
  }

  final case class AList[T <: HList](items: T)(implicit ev: isA[T]) extends A {
    override def foo: Int = 555
    override type I = AListIn[???]
  }

  trait isA[T] {
    def aux_foo(value: T): Int
  }

  trait isIn[T] {
    def aux_bar(value: T): Double
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  def alloc(a: A): In = ????

  def usage() = {
    val a1: A1 = A1() 
    val a2: A2 = A2() 

    val l: AList[::[A1, ::[A2, ::[A1, HNil]]]] = AList(a1 :: a2 :: a1 :: HNil) 

    val a1In: A1In = A1In(1.2) 
    val a2In: A2In = A2In(9.3) 

    val lIn: AListIn[::[A2In, ::[A1In, HNil]]] = AListIn(a2In :: a1In :: HNil)
  }

}
```

How can I fix it so it works as expected?
E.g how do I get correct type in place of `???` which is a proper type `HList` being result of applying `isA -> isIn` type mapping. The mapping must follow the natural association of `A -> In` mapping defined as `type I <: In` in `trait A`
And how to implement `alloc` function which for any concrete instance of `In` will produce corresponding instance of `A`?
Should concrete implementations of `In` be path dependent types of corresponding `A`s?

Below is the code for `isA` the code for `isIn` is analogous

```
trait isA[T] {
    def aux_foo(value: T): Int
  }

  object isA {
    // "Summoner" method
    def apply[T](implicit enc: isA[T]): isA[T] = enc

    // "Constructor" method
    def instance[T](func: T => Int): isA[T] = new isA[T] {
      override def aux_foo(value: T): Int = func(value)
    }

    implicit def a1Encoder: isA[A1] = instance(i => 4)
    implicit def a2Encoder: isA[A2] = instance(i => 9)

    implicit def hnilEncoder: isA[HNil] = instance(hnil => 0)

    implicit def hlistEncoder[H, T <: HList](implicit
                                             hInstance: Lazy[isA[H]],
                                             tInstance: isA[T]
                                            ): isA[H :: T] = instance {
      case h :: t => hInstance.value.aux_foo(h) + tInstance.aux_foo(t)
    }

    implicit def genericInstance[A, R](implicit
                                       generic: Generic.Aux[A, R],
                                       rInstance: Lazy[isA[R]]
                                      ): isA[A] = instance { value => rInstance.value.aux_foo(generic.to(value)) }
  }
```

Comment: It seems like you want a type class that would indicate a mapping from an `A` to its `In` instead of (or at least in addition to) the type member, but it's a little hard to guess the intent from the walls of code.

Comment: The intention is to have `usage()` produce vals of specified types.